# How to give each a element his specific url - PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I working on a simple project, and basically what I am doing is that I am creating a simple page from admin panel and then displays it in another page using iframe...

So in the process of displaying the page names, I managed to display all the page names that I have in the database. However, when I try to give them a link so when the user click on them, it redirects them to the specific page. So if there is a page named: new york and he clicks on it, it goes to: /pages/newYork.php ...

The problem: When I give them a link, only 1 page link is given for all the pages. Example: If I had cities named: New York, Bangkok and Amsterdam, the link for all of those pages is only for New york.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
require_once '../connect.php';
session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedinAdmin'])){

    }else{
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    // To display content:
    $realDisplay = '';
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cities");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $displayName = $row['name'];

        $realDisplay .= $displayName.'<br/>';
    }
    echo  "<u align='center'>Page names:";


?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Display Pages</title>
    <style>
        a{
            text-decoration:none;
            font-size:30px;
            color:skyblue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="color:red;">
        <a href="<?php echo 'pages/'.$displayName.'.php'?>">
            <?php echo $realDisplay;?>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any thoughts of how to solve this? Also, if there is a better way to do it then it would be great.

Thanks in advance for everybody :)

Answer (score 0):

First, move your loop to the page where you are actually going to display the data.

Second, keep your code clean and readable by putting things where they actually belong. ie. `<u align='center'>Page names:` doesn't belong where you put it. It goes in the body.

Third, don't forget to properly close your tags. `<u align='center'>Page names:` has no closing tag.

Finally, don't over-complicate it. You don't need two different vars for the same data row.

```
<?php 
require_once '../connect.php';
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['loggedinAdmin'])){

}else{
    header("Location: index.php");
}

// To display content:
//$realDisplay = '';
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cities");
//while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    //$displayName = $row['name'];
    //$realDisplay .= $displayName.'<br/>';
//}
//echo  "<u align='center'>Page names:";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Display Pages</title>
<style>
    a{
        text-decoration:none;
        font-size:30px;
        color:skyblue;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center"><u>Page names:</u></div>
    <div style="color:red;">
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
            $displayName =$row['name']
        ?>
            <a href="<?php echo 'pages/'.$displayName.'.php'?>"><?php echo $displayName;?></a><br>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I should make my codes cleaner :) 

Thanks for your answer! I can't up vote but it works :)

Comment: @JamalJubran If this answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to [accept that answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).
Also see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).